# Can Set be faster than Hashtable?

Tags: performance, dictionary, hash, hashtable, hashset

Sets are typically implemented as hashtables where keys are set members and values are some constant (True or something).
Since hashtable is a generalization of set, it could be possible to have a faster implementation of sets, but is there a faster implementation? Maybe such implementation is not based on hashtable at all? Or maybe it is is, but optimized in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Set be faster than Hashtable?

A "set" is any container that tracks distinct keys, supporting operations "insert(Key)", "erase(Key)", and "has(Key)".

A hash table can be used to do this - e.g. C++'s [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

A balanced binary tree can be used to do this - e.g. C++'s [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

While not efficient for more than a few tens or hundreds of Keys, contiguous memory (i.e. an array or `std::vector`) can store sorted elements for fairly fast (but still O(log N)) binary search lookup, with much slower insertion and erasure.  This can be optimal sometimes because it's CPU cache friendly.  But, because it quickly gets inefficient, C++ doesn't provide a contiguous-storage container with those three set operations (insert(Key), erase(key), find(key) as above)... you'd have to download an extra library or write your own.  C++ does have `std::binary_search`, `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` which will make it easy to implement.

Returning to your question:

> Can Set be faster than Hashtable?

They're not necessarily distinct things.  A set may be implemented using a hashtable, and sometimes that may be the best choice (particularly when there are a *lot* of keys, it's not expensive to hash the keys well enough to avoid excessive collisions, and it's cheap to compare keys.  Even then, there are different types of hash tables, and sometimes `unordered_set` won't be the fastest - you can google "fastest C++ hash table" and do some reading, e.g. https://engineering.fb.com/2019/04/25/developer-tools/f14/

Sometimes those other implementation choices - balanced binary trees or contiguous memory - will be faster than using a hash table.

Balanced binary trees tend to work well when there's a middling (few thousand to a million say) elements and it's cheap to work out whether one key is "less than" another key.

Turning to your other questions / assertions:

> Sets are typically implemented as hashtables where keys are set members and values are some constant (True or something).

Wrong: *sets* only store keys, they don't have "values" (whether boolean or otherwise).  If you want to keys and values, then that's called a *map*.  Maps can be implemented using all the same data structures as sets (hash tables, binary trees, contiguous storage), with the same performance compromises.  Maps are easily implemented akin to `set<std::pair<Key, Value>>`, where the needed lookup operations (hash, equals and or less-than) only consider the key.

I think I've adequately addressed your other speculation / questions....

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer with examples. Although, using your terminology, I was interested whether `Set` can be faster than `Map`. Your examples imply that they are the same because `Map` can also be implemented as a binary tree or based on contiguous memory, and the performance would be the same as for `Set` implemented that way.

Comment: @mf1337: that's right - the speed for sets and maps is still dominated by the same characteristics and operations (e.g. hashing or comparison of keys, collision handling in a hash table, memory layout / following pointers in separate chaining hash tables or binary trees).  Of course, maps have values to store as well, which take some extra memory and reduce CPU cache friendliness correspondingly, making them slower, but that's usually a subtle effect that's not worth consideration.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "speed" of a container. Every container supports some operations, and every operation has a complexity and preferred usecases. Some containers are good for consecutive reading, some for random access, some for insertions, some for appending, and so on. Before you start asking which container implementation as best for your usecase you need to describe this usecase. Nobody will say whether a hashtable is best in your case, if we do not know what this usecase even is.

If there was one container that was best in every situation, we'd be all using it, and there'd be no others.

That being said, I'd advise you against trying to optimize the standard library containers. Chances are, they'll be adequate for you without additional meddling. Optimizations should be done in the very end, if it turns out that your application is too slow, and the profiling shows that the containers are the exact problem. Usually they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have been more specific I guess.